# Media queries not working in Safari (Windows version)

Tags: css, safari, media-queries

I am designing a website which media queries works in every browser but Safari for Windows (it works fine in Safari for iOS). I have tried to figure out what's happening with my code or browser, but I hadn't been able.

I have developer the most simple page I've can, which has the following code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<title>My Page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>Content</div>
    <style>
        div {width: 400px; height: 400px; background: red;}
        @media screen and (max-width: 1000px){
            div {background-color: blue;}   
        }
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

That code is not working for me. However, if I change the condition to "-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0" the media query works.

Could someone help me with this simple problem?

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me on Safari.

Comment: [Safari for Windows is out of date](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history) as the last version is from 2012. I would ignore it and only test with Safari on Mac and iOS...

Comment: It may probably be the cause. I will focus on new versions.